# How can I make and discord js event that auto-remove a role?

Tags: javascript, discord, dom-events, discord.js

I want to make an event that if an user get a specific role, another specific role will be removed automatically.

Do I have to use the guildMemberUpdate?

Comment: Have you some code, maybe something you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => { 
 const firstRole = newMember.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name == "firstRole");
    const secondRole = newMember.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name == "secondRole" );
    if (newMember.roles.cache.has(firstRole.id) && newMember.roles.cache.has(secondRole.id)) {
        newMember.roles.remove(firstRole.id, "Had the first role");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right. You need to use the `guildMemberUpdate` event to track when a user gets/removes a role.

```js
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {

  const oldRoles = oldMember.roles;
  const newRoles = newMember.roles;

  // Check roles and execute your code.
});
```

So with the oldRoles/newRoles you can easily see if the user got a role and act in consequence.

Comment: please, can you give me an example? I can't think in a way to do this using these parameters...

Comment: Tell me what you exactly to do?

Comment: If a member get an specific role by leveling up, for example, another role that he had will be automatically removed, like, for example:

Role: LVL 1 will be removed when user gets Role: LVL 2